# Selenium: Able to locate the element by full XPath, failed to locate to locate by XPath with attribute selector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium. I'm trying to make a automate testing process for a datepicker. For example, I want to simulate a click on a specific date. E.g.: 2021-01-01:

[image: datepicker]

I am able to select the date element by the following code:

```
datepicker_day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]")
```

But it fails to do so by:

```
datepicker_day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[@title='2021-01-01']")
```

Here's the html code snippet (The whole html is too lengthy):

```
<div class="mx-datepicker-main mx-datepicker-popup" style="position: absolute; top: 256px; left: 548.219px;">
   <!----> 
   <div class="mx-datepicker-content">
      <!----> 
      <div class="mx-datepicker-body">
         <div class="mx-calendar mx-calendar-panel-date">
            <div class="mx-calendar-header"><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-double-left"><i class="mx-icon-double-left"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-left"><i class="mx-icon-left"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-double-right"><i class="mx-icon-double-right"></i></button> <button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-icon-right"><i class="mx-icon-right"></i></button> <span class="mx-calendar-header-label"><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-current-month">
               Feb
               </button><button type="button" class="mx-btn mx-btn-text mx-btn-current-year">
               2021
               </button></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-calendar-content">
               <table class="mx-table mx-table-year" style="display: none;">
                  <tr>
                     <td data-year="2020" class="cell">
                        <div>2020</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-year="2021" class="cell active">
                        <div>2021</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-year="2022" class="cell">
                        <div>2022</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-year="2023" class="cell">
                        <div>2023</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-year="2024" class="cell">
                        <div>2024</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-year="2025" class="cell">
                        <div>2025</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-year="2026" class="cell">
                        <div>2026</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-year="2027" class="cell">
                        <div>2027</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-year="2028" class="cell">
                        <div>2028</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-year="2029" class="cell">
                        <div>2029</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <table class="mx-table mx-table-month" style="display: none;">
                  <tr>
                     <td data-month="0" class="cell">
                        <div>Jan</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="1" class="cell active">
                        <div>Feb</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="2" class="cell">
                        <div>Mar</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-month="3" class="cell">
                        <div>Apr</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="4" class="cell">
                        <div>May</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="5" class="cell">
                        <div>Jun</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-month="6" class="cell">
                        <div>Jul</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="7" class="cell">
                        <div>Aug</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="8" class="cell">
                        <div>Sep</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td data-month="9" class="cell">
                        <div>Oct</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="10" class="cell">
                        <div>Nov</div>
                     </td>
                     <td data-month="11" class="cell">
                        <div>Dec</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <table class="mx-table mx-table-date">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <!----> 
                        <th>Su</th>
                        <th>Mo</th>
                        <th>Tu</th>
                        <th>We</th>
                        <th>Th</th>
                        <th>Fr</th>
                        <th>Sa</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="0" title="2021-01-31" class="cell not-current-month">
                           <div>31</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="1" title="2021-02-01" class="cell">
                           <div>1</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="2" title="2021-02-02" class="cell">
                           <div>2</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="3" title="2021-02-03" class="cell">
                           <div>3</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="4" title="2021-02-04" class="cell">
                           <div>4</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="5" title="2021-02-05" class="cell">
                           <div>5</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="6" title="2021-02-06" class="cell">
                           <div>6</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="7" title="2021-02-07" class="cell">
                           <div>7</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="8" title="2021-02-08" class="cell">
                           <div>8</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="9" title="2021-02-09" class="cell">
                           <div>9</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="10" title="2021-02-10" class="cell">
                           <div>10</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="11" title="2021-02-11" class="cell">
                           <div>11</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="12" title="2021-02-12" class="cell">
                           <div>12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="13" title="2021-02-13" class="cell">
                           <div>13</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="14" title="2021-02-14" class="cell">
                           <div>14</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="15" title="2021-02-15" class="cell today active">
                           <div>15</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="16" title="2021-02-16" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>16</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="17" title="2021-02-17" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>17</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="18" title="2021-02-18" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>18</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="19" title="2021-02-19" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>19</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="20" title="2021-02-20" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>20</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="21" title="2021-02-21" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>21</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="22" title="2021-02-22" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>22</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="23" title="2021-02-23" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>23</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="24" title="2021-02-24" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>24</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="25" title="2021-02-25" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>25</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="26" title="2021-02-26" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>26</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="27" title="2021-02-27" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>27</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="28" title="2021-02-28" class="cell disabled">
                           <div>28</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="29" title="2021-03-01" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>1</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="30" title="2021-03-02" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>2</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="31" title="2021-03-03" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>3</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="32" title="2021-03-04" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>4</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="33" title="2021-03-05" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>5</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="34" title="2021-03-06" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>6</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="mx-date-row">
                        <!----> 
                        <td data-day="35" title="2021-03-07" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>7</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="36" title="2021-03-08" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>8</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="37" title="2021-03-09" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>9</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="38" title="2021-03-10" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>10</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="39" title="2021-03-11" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>11</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="40" title="2021-03-12" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-day="41" title="2021-03-13" class="cell not-current-month disabled">
                           <div>13</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to sort it out for hours but I failed.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. As the datepicker isn't loaded until the datepicker field is focused, the code

```
datepicker_day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[@title='2021-01-01']")
```

should be placed after the field is being focused.

Also, the XPath is dynamic:

```
/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div
```

vs

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div
```

So it is better to use:

```
//title[@title='2021-02-01']
```